# Joomla conditional pages and menus

Tags: joomla, conditional-statements, joomla1.5

I'm trying to make a "Chapter selector" for my organization's website. I want to be able to select, say, the "Bay Area chapter" and have the site display articles and events for the Bay Area chapter (while keeping the chapter-independent parts of the site the same). How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd need a little more detail but here are some of the things to consider -

1. I am a fan of K2 for being able to nest categories, but you can at least categorize all of your Chapter information in to separate categories within a single section in the Joomla content manager.
2. For each Category you will need a menu item - Articles > Category > Category blog Layout
3. In the module manager you will need corresponding modules that display category related information. Be sure to associate the modules to the correct menu items in the module's Menu Assignment area.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the chapter selector as a menu. Create a menu to contain your chapters and then publish a module for that menu which  allows you to pick your items with that chapter.